# My Twitter page looks glitched

Tags: twitter

I haven't been able to see any Twitter images for about two years now; even in news articles the images just show a blank white box with a 'not allowed' icon (black circle with a line drawn diagonally through it) in the upper left corner of the blank box.  My Twitter page (when I login) looks all messed up, too.  No background, just rows of text all smashed up against the left-hand side of the page.

I'd like to be able to view Twitter images especially when they're displayed (as Twitter images) on other sites.  I'd also like to make sense of my Twitter page!! This is how the page pretty much looks to me on my PC:

```
*'Skip to content 
Twitter 

•   Home Home Home, current page. New Tweets available.  
•   Moments Moments Moments, current page.  
•   Notifications Notifications Notifications, current page. 0   
•  Messages   
 Search query  Search Twitter   
Recent searches
Clear All • Remove  
Saved searches
• Remove  
•  
• 
 In this conversation 
 Verified accountProtected Tweets @    
•
•
• Profile and settings  
◦ Dia Horn 
@Diah1

◦
◦ Profile  
◦ Lists  
◦ Moments  
◦
◦ Twitter Ads  
◦ Analytics  
◦
◦Settings and privacy
◦Help Center
◦ Keyboard shortcuts 
◦ Log out 
   • Tweet  
Dia Horn 
@Diah1  
• Tweets 48  
• Following 13  
• Followers 17  
Who to follow
·  Refresh · View all 
Find people you know  
false
•© 2017 Twitter
•About
•Help Center
•Terms
•Privacy policy
•Cookies
•Ads info
•Brand
•Blog
•Status
•Apps
•Jobs
•Businesses
•Developers
Advertise with Twitter  Advertise with Twitter 
Close   
Photo
Close   
Mute Notifications
Mute notifications duration 
For 1 hour  For 8 hours  For 1 week  Forever  
Cancel Mute 
Close   
Go to a person's profile
Recent searches
Clear All • Remove  
Saved searches
• Remove  
•  
• 
 In this conversation 
 Verified accountProtected Tweets @    
•
•
Suggested users 
•    Verified accountProtected Tweets @   
•
•    Verified accountProtected Tweets @   
•
•  
Close   
Promote this Tweet
Close   
Block
Cancel Block 
•Tweet with a location
You can add location information to your Tweets, such as your city or precise location, from the web and via third-party applications. You always have the option to delete your Tweet location history. Learn more 
Turn on Not now 
Close   
Share Location
Foursquare 
Results from  Yelp 
Send 
Close   
Your lists
Close   
Create a new list
List name  
Description  Under 100 characters, optional 
Privacy 
 Public · Anyone can follow this list   Private · Only you can access this list  
Save list 
Close   
Close   
Security challenge
There appears to be some suspicious activity on your account. In order to continue, please solve the challenge below. 
Cancel Submit 
Close   
Copy link to Tweet
Here's the URL for this Tweet. Copy it to easily share with friends.
Close   
Embed this Tweet
Embed this Video*'
```

Okay, you get the idea.  Please help, anyone?

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser? On a different network? Do you have some sort of ad-blocker? It sounds like the CSS simply isn't being loaded.

Comment: I don't know what the 'CSS' is.  Yes, I've tried a different network and browser, and I have no ad-blocker programs, either.  Any additional advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks ale.